# To construct GridFS objects with mongo java driver v3.0 Released

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

**Context:**

- MongoDB 3.0 Released
- Java Driver Version 3.0

If I connect to mongodb how it has described into the mongo java driver documentation, how do I obtain a new GridFS object? There are not a constructor for this signature (MongoDatabase db, String bucket).

```
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(_userDb, _database, _passDb.toCharArray());
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(_host, _port), Arrays.asList(credential));
MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase(_database);
```

I would like to avoid use deprecated method. It appears that casting is not possible

```
GridFS gfsPhoto = new GridFS((DB) mongoDatabase, "photos");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mongoClient.getDB(_database)`.  GridFS support in the new API didn't make the schedule for the 3.0 schedule but should be in 3.1.  For now you're perfectly safe using the old `DB` API.  It's your only choice, really.

Answer (score 1):

Could be good to mention. MongoDB version 3.2 it's changed into GridFSBucket. Took me awhile to find the new solution.

```
// Create a gridFSBucket using the default bucket name "fs"
GridFSBucket gridFSBucket = GridFSBuckets.create(myDatabase);

// Create a gridFSBucket with a custom bucket name "files"
GridFSBucket gridFSBucket = GridFSBuckets.create(myDatabase, "files");
```

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/driver/reference/gridfs/